# Custom Mule Cloud Connector with Axis2 Client

Tags: mule, apache-axis, mule-studio, axiom

I have developed a custom cloud connector for Mule.  I have developed it in IntelliJ using Maven.  I generated code from a 3rd party WSDL using Axis2 and XMLBeans.  I have developed test cases that pass and show the expected results after interacting with the web service.  "mvn clean package" successfully passes all tests and builds the site.

The problem I am having is using it in anypoint building out a Mule project.  I have added the Axis2 1.6.3 libs to the classpath root of the jvm created by Anypoint when launching the application.  When I submit a request that interacts with my connector, I get the following error:

> ---
>
> Message               : null (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError).
>   Message payload is of type: String Type                  :
>   org.mule.api.MessagingException Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
>   JavaDoc               :
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
>   Payload               : Testing
>   ******************************************************************************** Exception stack is:
>   1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)   org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator:72 (null)
>   2. null (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)   org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription:72 (null)
>   3. null (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>   org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
>   ******************************************************************************** Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.(DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.java:72)

Looking at DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator, for axiom-api1.2.14, I see the following at line 72:

> Enumeration e =
>   classLoader.getResources(ImplementationFactory.DESCRIPTOR_RESOURCE);

The static reference is to an axiom.xml file.  I have tried adding the file manually but continue to get the null pointer error.  This code is used by the generated code to make a connection via the client but not impacted by my code directly.  Is there something I am missing with being able to use Axis2 within a Cloud Connector in Mule ESB?  Why would it work in the maven test but not in anypoint?

Additional Info:

Axis2 1.6.3
Axiom* 1.2.14
Mule ESB 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that Axiom is loaded by the bootstrap classloader of the JVM. I doubt that doing this is the recommended way to deploy things on Anypoint.

Comment: You are right, I intentionally loaded it in the bootstrap class loader.  Mule ESB 3.7 references an older version of Axiom.  If I do not load it in the bootstrap, I get a method not found error because of the older version of Axiom.

Comment: I think the right way to do this is to add the JARs to $MULE_HOME/lib/user.

Comment: If I switch to the way you mention, I get the following (at least I think I am doing it right, I added Axis2 1.6.3 to use libraries in the run config):

Message               : org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory()Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMMetaFactory; (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError). Message payload is of type: String
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               :

Comment: correction to above, I added Axis2 1.6.3 libs to the "user entries" under classpath, in the run configs

Comment: What I'm referring to is item 2 in https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/classloader-control-in-mule.

Comment: Accepting your answer because technically, you are right but it is not solving the issue I am running into.  I opened a new one that is more accurate on what the issue is:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164577/classloader-overrides-not-working-in-mule